# Как заставить FileOutputStream распаковывать файлы с русскими названиями на android?

Tags: java, android, кириллица, zip

Пишу программу на android, и там в ней я хотел реализовать возможность импорта в программу, через zip файл. Но возникла проблема с русскими буквами.

У меня не получается распаковать файлы, названия которых написаны русскими буквами. Есть ли какое-то решение для данной проблемы?

**Обновление**

Не знаю чем вас смутила данная фраза)) Я в винде запаковываю файлы, и кидаю на телефон. В архиве могут быть файлы, с русскими названиями, например видео.avi, как раз, когда в цикле дело доходит до русских названий, срабатывает исключение. Код простейший:

```
 public boolean mUnpackZipFile(String mArchivePath,String mOutPutStream) {
    InputStream inputstream;
    ZipInputStream zipinputstream;
    Message msg;

    try {
        String filename;
        inputstream = new FileInputStream(mArchivePath);
        zipinputstream = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(inputstream));
        ZipEntry mZipEntry;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int count;

        while ((mZipEntry = zipinputstream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            filename = mZipEntry.getName();

            if (mZipEntry.isDirectory()) {
                File fmd = new File(mOutPutStream + filename);
                fmd.mkdirs();
                continue;
            }

            FileOutputStream fileoutputstream = new FileOutputStream(mOutPutStream + filename);

            msg = h.obtainMessage(FILE_NAME, filename);
            h.sendMessage(msg);

            while ((count = zipinputstream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                fileoutputstream.write(buffer, 0, count);
            }
            fileoutputstream.close();
            zipinputstream.closeEntry();
        }

        zipinputstream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

С латиницей нет никаких проблем. Там все распаковывается... В `ZipInputStream` в конструкторе, для андроида, вроде нет возможности ставить кодировку...